# Regression robust to changes in model, post-training

Tags: multiple-regression, robust

I am trying to estimate a single variable $y$ from a set of predictors $X$, which are highly colinear.
I've read about ridge regression and lasso which, in my understanding, place penalties to favor a solution involving the least amount of predictors that have the highest coefficients.

However in my application, $X$ is produced by sensors which may suddenly fail. Take, for instance the sensor producing input $X_1$: it had been identified as one of the best predictors, but suddenly becomes disconnected and has a "flat" reading of zero. If $X_1$ had been given the highest coefficient in the regression for $y$,the result would be completely wrong.
Instead, I'm looking for a more robust regression, where perhaps the aim is to make every predictor contribute equally, so that when one input becomes erratic, the overall error is minimized thanks to the contribution other predictors.

In the past I had experimented with individually regressing $y$ using each $X$ (one at a time), and then calculating the median of all regressions. Is there a standard algorithm that achieves the same? I feel like PCA could help, but don't know how to work it.

Comment: Is it important to use regression?  Something like random forest could work well, where you also hold predictors out from consideration on entire trees.  Then if you lose an sensor, you can cut out the trees that use that predictor, and average the predictions from the other trees.

Comment: Also, I don't think this is a very accurate description or ridge regression: "avor a solution involving the least amount of predictors that have the highest coefficient".  It does the opposite, favoring solutions with a large number of coefficients with small estimates.

Comment: Comment #1: I had thought of RF, but since the senors' values are linearly related, I thought I could use a model that's simpler and easier to interpret.
Comment #2: So I had misunderstood what ridge regression does - and based on your comment, RR is exactly what I'm looking for (?)

Comment: Well, sort of.  The issue is that, if a sensor drops out, it doesnt make sense to just plug zero in for its value in the ridge regression.  You really want the coefficients for the correlated variables to adapt to its absence, but ridge wont do that automatically.  This is where the RF type of model helps.  You could do something similar, but bag together lots of linear regressions fit on random subsets of your data to random subsets of your predictors.  I.e., bag some linear or ridge regressions.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thank you. 
And I should mention, there's no trivial way to notice sensors failing (they don't always read zero, it was only an example).

Comment: That's interesting.  I havent thought much about models that are robust to some of their input channels being corrupted without knowing it, that's very interesting.  It may be a good idea to add noise to the predictors used in the model in some way reflective of what you expect to encounter, or actually train using data where some records are from failed sensors.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but from what I've read "**Denoising autoencoders**" are designed with this in mind. It's a Neural Network trained to rebuild "clean" data from corrupted (or noisy) inputs.
It implies that you have either, for training purposes:

- A set of both original (clean) data and corrupted data
- Original data, and a way to generate corrupted data

I haven't found anything in "classical stats"